# Diversified Rubik's Cube

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, optimization, rubiks-cube

I have, cleverly I hope, shuffled my Rubik's Cube for a while. I could not find a position where, for each faces, all colors appear 3 times or less. I always had a or several faces with at least 4 of the same colors.

This puzzle is to determine what is the minimum number of colors $X$ such that there exists a Rubik's Cube position which for all faces, all colors appear less than $X$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each color appears $9$ times total, so an average of $9/6$ times per face, which implies a lower bound

> $$X \ge \lceil 9/6 \rceil = 2.$$

Without loss of generality, color $c$ appears at the center of face $c$.  Here is such an assignment of colors to faces, where each row or column sums to $9$ and the diagonal is positive:

\begin{matrix}
\text{color}\backslash\text{face}  &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 \\ 
\hline
1 &1 &2 &2 &2 &0 &2 \\
2 &2 &2 &0 &2 &2 &1 \\
3 &2 &0 &2 &1 &2 &2 \\
4 &1 &1 &1 &2 &2 &2 \\
5 &1 &2 &2 &2 &2 &0 \\
6 &2 &2 &2 &0 &1 &2 \\
\end{matrix}

Not sure whether these counts are actually physically realizable on the cube.

I played with an actual cube and got

> $X \le 3$:

> [image]

> (The top right corner is orange.)

> [image]

Comment: Do you choose to upvote only the best of the best questions?

Comment: @JLee I haven't kept track, but I probably upvote answers more often than questions.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Just something I noticed. You provide very high-quality answers. I always enjoy reading them & learning. So thanks for that. Often I see that there are zero upvotes on a question/puzzle that you answer, & I assume, "He thought this puzzle/question was worth answering (many times in great detail with lots of time spent) but not worth an upvote?" To me, the vast majority of the time, if I am going to spend more than a tiny bit of time on something, my upvote of the puzzle is a "thank you" for providing me with something interesting to think about. But that's just me, and everyone's different.

Comment: I see. I took some time just now to upvote many questions I have answered, including at least one of yours.  I hit my vote limit for the day but will keep this in mind.